# Generate a random html hex color with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate a HTML color code in hex, e.g. `#8D46CA`. I don't care what value it returns as long as it's a fairly random but valid R,G,B color code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generates a random number between 0 and 0xFFFFFF, and converts it to hex:

```
select '#'
       || to_char(
              dbms_random.value(0, to_number('FFFFFF','XXXXXX'))
              ,'fm0XXXXX')
from dual;
```

Example outputs:

```
#37DC45
#05C948
#00000A
```

In the conversion format, `X` means "convert to hexadecimal", `fm` means "don't include the leading space', and `0` means "pad the result with zeroes if necessary'.

If you prefer lowercase, change the `X` into `x`.